# При наведении,появляется в фон в div

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении фон становился виден именно в данном блоке?

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bg"></div>

    <div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

.myDiv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 400%;
  padding: 0px;
}

.myDiv .bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url('http://lh6.ggpht.com/stod84/SLl3qiduLtI/AAAAAAAAB_g/BQgmmyvaGxw/s400/css-background.jpg') center center;
  opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:none;
}.child{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;

}
```

Тут все http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/sbGb4/764/

Comment: Что если делать фон блока прозрачным, тогда сквозь него будет видно фон.

Comment: Если ответ чем-то не устраивает, это можно написать в комментариях к нему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, можно так сделать. Хотя что-то такое чувство, что перемудрил :)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 262px;
  width: 262px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 400%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: url('http://lh6.ggpht.com/stod84/SLl3qiduLtI/AAAAAAAAB_g/BQgmmyvaGxw/s400/css-background.jpg') center center;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  border: 10px solid white;
  outline-offset: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: white;
}

.child:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>
</div>
```